# What's the difference between these two codes? One works, One doesn't?

Tags: html, css, transformation

I am trully baffled by what's going on. The two codes we have here are supposed to be 3D transformations in CSS. Okay let's begin.

Here's the one I attempted by following a tutorial. It shows the text but no animation. Almost seem CSS is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .flip3D{ width:240px; height:200px; margin:10px; float:left;}
                .fli3D > .front
                    {   
                        position:absolute;
                        transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
                        background: #FC0; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 10px;
                        backface-visibility: hidden;
                        transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
                    }
                .kfli3D > .back
                    {
                        position:absolute;
                        transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
                        background: #80BFFF; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 10px;
                        backface-visibility: hidden;
                        transition: transform .5s linear 0s; 
                    }
                .flip3D:hover > .front
                    {   
                        transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
                    }   
                flip3D:hover > .back
                    {
                        transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
                    }   
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="flip3D">
      <div class="back">Box 1 - Back</div>
      <div class="front">Box 1 - Front</div>
    </div>

    <div class="flip3D">
       <div class="back">Box 2 - Back</div>
       <div class="front">Box 2 - Front</div>
     </div>

    <div class="flip3D">
       <div class="back">Box 3 - Back</div>
       <div class="front">Box 3 - Front</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Okay, here's the official version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.flip3D{ width:240px; height:200px; margin:10px; float:left; }
.flip3D > .front{
    position:absolute;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
    background:#FC0; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3D > .back{
    position:absolute;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg );
    background: #80BFFF; width:240px; height:200px; border-radius: 7px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3D:hover > .front{
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg );
}
.flip3D:hover > .back{
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back">Box 1 - Back</div>
  <div class="front">Box 1 - Front</div>
</div>
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back">Box 2 - Back</div>
  <div class="front">Box 2 - Front</div>
</div>
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="back">Box 3 - Back</div>
  <div class="front">Box 3 - Front</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class names in the first example are

```
.fli3D > .front { ... };
.kfli3D > .back { ... };
```

and in the second ( working one ) are

```
.flip3D > .front { ... };
.flip3D > .back  { ... };
```

So basically you have typo in your class CSS selector.